# 500 when publishing my Nextjs app on Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify, http-status-code-500

What could be the possible cause of the "Internal Server Error" with status code 500 when publishing my app on Netlify, based on the error message and log provided?

I have found that when I remove components that **"use client"** from my main page, it starts working again. What could I be doing wrong?

I need to use **"useClient"** for managing state with useState.

Additionally, I noticed that when I type **"/about"** in the URL and then navigate back to the **main page** using a link, it starts working again. However, the issue reoccurs when I reload the page.

P.S. The console is prompting me to visit this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred

[image: files]

Comment: Based on this information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607999/next-js-application-error-a-client-side-exception-has-occurred-see-the-browser, I have identified the reason for the issue. However, I still require the use of "useClient" in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I think this link might be helpful:
https://answers.netlify.com/t/server-edge-not-defined-error-on-nextjs-ssr-functions-cause-site-to-return-500-errors/91793

I tried [the workaround they suggested in the comments](https://answers.netlify.com/t/server-edge-not-defined-error-on-nextjs-ssr-functions-cause-site-to-return-500-errors/91793/31) and adding the prebuild file solved the issue for me.

Comment: For my part, I switched back to the Next.js system with the arrangement of pages in the "pages" directory instead of src/app and the page.js.